# asp.net mvc - searching

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, lucene.net

I have a requirement where a user can type in a keyword and the search should look at 4 columns to match against (name, city, state, zip) and return the search results. I'm wondering if I should use a LIKE clause, Free Text Search, Lucene .net, etc. also, I am using sql server.

Pros/Cons?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any idea of the number of rows you expect (by order of magnitude)?

Comment: maybe a thousand or so a year. hard to say as this site is brand new without a user base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like clause would be slow for lots of rows, but should be ok for 1k rows/year (then, in 10 years you'll probably want to optimize it).